# Meteor: How to list the installed packages

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

I'm starting with Meteor, and I'd like to know how to list the installed packages.

`meteor list` would only list the available packages in the registry.

Edit: Since meteor 0.9.0.1 `meteor list` lists the available packages in the project.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Update**: as of meteor 1.0, the command is now

```
meteor list
```

Comment: Why is this not in the --help!

Comment: @meawoppl Actually this have an help, try `meteor help list` you'll find it. :)

Comment: Which is basically the same as doing: `cat .meteor/packages`

Comment: looks like using is not valid anymore. latest version of meteor spews error.

Comment: you dont need --using

Comment: @Bjørn Bråthen : Difference between `cat` and `list` is that `list` will provide version number of the package as well, whereas `cat` will just display contents of the packages file

Comment: another way is to look at .meteor/versions since it will display also packages  installed as dependencies from the packages you choose. Useful tip to remember for debugging.

Answer (score 26):

I think it's just `meteor list` now (as of 0.9.0.1).

Answer (score 6):

```
meteor list
```

does the trick for meteor 1.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @jubobs *yes this provides an answer*

Comment: @Jubops my answer is correct. I have meteor 1.0 version and meteor list command lists the packages used by an application. I don't have enough reputation to post comment for starter's post.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look into the ./meteor/packages file, which is a plain text file, all installed packages are listed in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by typing `meteor list` on the command line on your project directory. Or, Browse into .meteor folder on your project directory and view the packages file with your favorite text editor.

Comment: Can you view it with your second favourite text editor?

Answer (score 1):

meteor list
Works fine for the latest meteor version, 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way to Found packages Folder

> .meteor/packages

Open this file on Editor. Listed All Packages

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all the packages then  you can go to `.meteor/packages` there you'll find all the packages installed.

For reference, you can check this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as of version 0.9.0.1 to search package: `meteor search nameofpackage`

Answer (score 0):

An advantage with using `meteor list` compared to look in `.meteor/packages` is that the version numbers is included in the list command and * marks outdated versions.

Answer (score 0):

on command line windows or terminal type

1. `meteor list`. This command will list all the packages that you add to your project.
2. `meteor list-platforms`.Lists all of the platforms that have been explicitly added to your project.

On linux cd ~/meteor/packages or on windows search in .meteor/packages.and run command line `meteor list`
If you haven't installed meteor-tools type `meteor add windows:meteor-tool`
.
You should read [Meteor command line](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html)